# Custom Auto Configuration in Spring Boot cannot find DataSource with ConditionalOnBean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-config, spring-boot-configuration

I have a problem with Spring Boot version 2.0.1.RELEASE (in Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE the below configuration worked nice).

Could somebody help me out please why this configuration is not working?
I have this configuration and this config did not match the `ConditionalOnBean` condition.

The `AutoConfigureOrder` / `Order` / `AutoConfigureAfter` seems that doesn't have any effect.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({DataSource.class, JpaRepository.class})
@ConditionalOnBean(DataSource.class)
@AutoConfigureAfter(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.data.jpa.repositories", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
@AutoConfigureOrder(LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Order(LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class MyJpaAuditAutoConfiguration {

    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @Bean
    public MyTransactionHelper transactionHelper() {
        return new MyTransactionHelper();
    }

}
```

In `spring.factories` I have:

```
     org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=org.example.MyJpaAuditAutoConfiguration
```

Application start output for this configuration:

```
DataSourceAutoConfiguration matched:
  - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
```

...

```
JpaAuditAutoConfiguration:
  Did not match:
     - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type javax.sql.DataSource (OnBeanCondition)
  Matched:
     - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
     - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
```

In my opinion, the config class is evaluated before `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` and that's the reason why the bean cannot be found.
Other configs like `DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration` found the bean.

```
DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration matched:
  - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate', 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
  - @ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator management.health.defaults.enabled is considered true (OnEnabledHealthIndicatorCondition)
  - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'dataSource' (OnBeanCondition)
```

Comment: did you try removing `@Order` and `@AutoConfigureOrder`?

Comment: Actually I start without those and added hoped that helps, so with or without those doesn't works.

Comment: Curious whether you found a solution to this problem eventually? I'm stuck on a very similar issue (but using JMS ConnectionFactory instead of DataSource).

Comment: Please check my answer for the possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spring boot upgrade to version `2.1.2.RELEASE` it was solved automatically.

(I renamed some classes in the answer)

So in `Spring Boot version 2.1.2.RELEASE`:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnBean(DataSource.class)
@ConditionalOnClass({DataSource.class, JpaRepository.class})
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.data.jpa.repositories", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
@AutoConfigureAfter(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
public class JpaTransactionHelperAutoConfiguration {

    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @Bean
    public TransactionHelper transactionHelper() {
        return new TransactionHelper();
    }

}
```

NOTE: by removing the `@AutoConfigureAfter(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)` it won't work in Spring Boot version 2.1.2.RELEASE.

In `Spring Boot version 2.0.1.RELEASE` I just removed the `ConditionalOnBean` annotation:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({DataSource.class, JpaRepository.class})
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.data.jpa.repositories", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
@AutoConfigureAfter(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
public class JpaTransactionHelperAutoConfiguration {

    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @Bean
    public TransactionHelper transactionHelper() {
        return new TransactionHelper();
    }

}
```

Comment: I am working with v1.5.12.RELEASE in some legacy application. Unfortunately, neither of those solutions works here. :-(